# Xamarin Forms crossplatform local notifications with action buttons

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, notifications

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms app for Android and iOS that needs to do crossplatfom local notifications with actions from a background service that I am running.

I have figured out how to do xamarin and not platform based local notifications but I can't seem to figure out how to implement action buttons for local notifications so that i can act according to them.

I am very thankful and appreciative for any help or advice given.

Comment: Have you googled the title of your question? This sounds like basic functionality, that should be covered in existing docs, tutorials, youtube videos, and previous StackOverflow Q&As. Bottom line: it is your job to research, and get to the point where you **write code**. If that code does not work, THEN post question here, showing the code, describing what you expected to happen, and saying what actually happened. Narrow it down to a **specific** problem. Ideally, identifying one or a few lines of code that don't work as expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have found a **Crossplatform** way to implement notification actions with the following notification plugin

[Plugin.LocalNotification](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification/wiki/Notification-with-Action)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the notification's layout is RemoteViews, you can use [setCustomContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/android.app.notification.builder.setcustomcontentview?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12&viewFallbackFrom=xamarin-android-sdk-9) to customize the notification view. In IOS, you can do it by adding [custom UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#:%7E:text=in%20the%20Notification.-,Creating%20custom%20user%20interfaces,-To%20create%20a).